# How to make foldername.domainname.com?

Tags: php, asp.net, dns

I want to make url like foldername.domainname.com.
Suppose i have folder structure like following:

images
css
others
index.php

I want to know that is it possible to make domain like images.domainname.com by php programming or not.

If it is possible how can i do. Please suggest me.

Regards,
Krishna

Answer (score 3):

You need to create a [DNS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System) record for a [subdomain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subdomain).

Comment: I'll note wildcard can be used. So you'd have two records, one for the domain than the 2nd which covers all subdomains.

Answer (score 3):

I guess you will have to use wildcard subdomain for that, you can't do it with just PHP.It allows you not have to setup DNS for each subdomain, and instead use apache rewrites for the redirection, like:

```
<VirtualHost 111.22.33.55>
    DocumentRoot /www/subdomain
    ServerName www.domain.tld
    ServerAlias *.domain.tld
</VirtualHost>
```

See some article [here](http://steinsoft.net/index.php?site=programming/articles/apachewildcarddomain)
Hope it helps

Comment: To expand on your answer; for nginx its `server_name domainname.com *.domainname.com;`